# What type of batteries are used in airline planes?

Tags: airliner, jet, electrical-system

In Embraer 145 and Boeing 777
I mean material, recharge cycle,  nominal current and voltages. From the comments I don't understand the difference if the plane is turboprop or turbofan.

Comment: What size plane? 747? Cessna? Somewhere in between?

Comment: Are you looking for battery capacities or discharge profiles for a start (assuming an S/G on smaller turbofans and turboprops). Your question just isn't very clear on what you are looking for.

Comment: Is your question about the batteries being Li-ion or Lead acid, etc, as explained [here](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Aircraft_Batteries#Battery_Types)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this Concorde battery page, the Embraer E-145 can use a 44 Ah, 24 VDC Lead-Acid batter: [Concorde RG-422](http://www.concordebattery.com/aag3.php?id=1304)

The Embraer E-145 can also use Ni-Cd batteries.

The Boeing 777 uses Ni-Cd batteries as well: [Boeing 777 Saft Batteries](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/new-777-battery-system-launched-52436/)